# Fill in missing values with fractional sequence

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like such:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                  interval = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3),
                  value = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 1, 0, 50))
```

For each ID the value represents a change from a non zero value. Most of the values are 0 as there is no change.  What I would like is for each ID to replace the 0 with an increment of the difference between the 2 non-zero values. Ideally the increment should be equal so if we were to have the 2 points on a line we could draw a line between them with the new points.  So, in the example above we would have:

```
 id interval value
   1        1     1
   1        2     17.5
   1        3     34
   1        4     50.5
   1        5     67
   1        6     83.5
   1        7     100
   2        1     1
   2        2     24.5
   2        3     50
```

where each increment for ID 1 is

`val7-val1/(row_number(7)-row_number(1))`

but it has to work by specifying the non-zero row numbers per group, which is id number.  The values filled in are just the fractions, so it assumes a linear trend.  Bonus points if somehow it can use a non-linear or weighted trend.

Bonus points if the solution allows me to do this in a dplyr chain. It could be simple and I am just blanking on the phrasing.

**Edited for clarity of output. I do not want to just paste row numbers or whole number sequences, but the fractional differences of the 2 values added to the prior row's value**

**Edit: The difference between values may not be positive.  Also, it is not always from the first row. It could also look like the following:***

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                  interval = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3),
                  value = c(1, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 50, 10, 10, 50))
```

where I would want:

````
id interval value
   1        1     1
   1        2     34
   1        3     77
   1        4     100
   1        5     -83.33333
   1        6     -66.666
   1        7     50
   2        1     0
   2        2     25
   2        3     50```

And then it starts over again with the next non zero value from the original data like so:

id interval value
   1        7     50
   1        8     100
   1        9     150
   1        10    200
   2        1     50
   2        2     30
   2        3     10```
````

Comment: *a non-linear trend derived from the previous differences for each ID* or for each *interval*? Can you edit the question with an output example of what you mean?

Comment: I edited my post, but it is definitely not any solution where just pasting the row number would suffice. I have altered my sample data and output to reflect this. Neither of those links suffice.

Answer (score 2):

An option is

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(value = row_number())
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
#      id interval value
#   <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
# 1     1        1     1
# 2     1        2     2
# 3     1        3     3
# 4     1        4     4
# 5     1        5     5
# 6     1        6     6
# 7     1        7     7
# 8     2        1     1
# 9     2        2     2
#10     2        3     3
```

#### Update

```
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(value1 = seq(value[1], value[n()], by = (value[n()] - value[1])/(n() -1)))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
#      id interval value value1
#   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1        1     1    1  
# 2     1        2     0   17.5
# 3     1        3     0   34  
# 4     1        4     0   50.5
# 5     1        5     0   67  
# 6     1        6     0   83.5
# 7     1        7   100  100  
# ...
```

which would give similar output to `approx` (in the comments)

```
df %>%
    mutate(value = na_if(value, 0)) %>%
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(value = approx(value, xout = row_number())$y)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
#      id interval value
#   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1        1   1  
# 2     1        2  17.5
# 3     1        3  34  
# 4     1        4  50.5
# 5     1        5  67  
# 6     1        6  83.5
# 7     1        7 100  
# ...
```

Comment: This will not work if the interval is not an increment of 1

Comment: doesn't seem to work on columns with values <=0 and gives the error Error in if (by == 0 && del == 0) return(from) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution is to use `ave`.

```
df$value2 <- ave(df$id, df$id, FUN = seq_along)
identical(df$value, df$value2)
#[1] TRUE
```

**Data.**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
id interval value
   1        1     1
   1        2     2
   1        3     3
   1        4     4
   1        5     5
   1        6     6
   1        7     7
   2        1     1
   2        2     2
   2        3     3
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Will this value work if the interval number and value are not the same?

Comment: After OP's edit a `baseR` option would be `df$value2 <- with(df, ave(replace(value, value == 0, NA), id, FUN = function(x) approx(x, xout = seq_along(x))$y))`

Comment: @markus that doesn't work for some reason with my actual data. I have no NA values in the sample or real data, yet my actual data throws the error  ```Error in approx(x, xout = seq_along(x)) : 
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate``` and when I remove the NA portion```Error in replace(arr_change, arr_change == 0) : 
  argument "values" is missing, with no default```